# How can I tell if a site is using open SSL, and which version?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed

In light of the Open SSL Heartbleed bug, I'd like to make sure I'm not putting any personal information in any system that is using Open SSL that is vulnerable.

So, from my browser (IE 11) how can I tell if 1. a website is using Open SSL, and 2. if so, what version of Open SSL?

I know I can view the security certificates by clicking on the little lock in the address bar, but from what I see, there's nothing that says Open SSL, nor the version.

Thanks.

Comment: you can not. period.

Comment: To assuage your fears, use [Qualys SSLlabs assessment tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) for the site you're interested in.

Comment: @DeerHunter thank you. Would you like to put that into a real answer so I can give you points?

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to tell from version info, mostly because you can't guarantee that it's accurate or even available.

Browser plugins are check sites are surfacing that allow you essentially test the exploit to identify if the site is vulnerable and that's really the only way to know for sure.